# What is this first-person perspective game set in a tropical jungle?

Tags: game-identification

Have a look at this picture of a friend playing a first-person perspective game set in what seems to be a tropical jungle. None of us remember its name. Does anyone know what it is?

[image: Photo of a black-and-silver television displaying a game, with red blinds behind the television. A person with long nails holds a black Playstation 3 controller framed just below it, and another can be seen lying on a black surface in the background. The screen contains a first-person view of the passenger seat of a jerry-rigged and rusted jeep-style vehicle. The vehicle is being driven over a dirt road with lush tropical vegetation. To the left of the road, there is a fern, with a rock behind it, and a large tree with what seems to be very thick branches that split off the trunk very low down. Ahead is a copse of indistinguishable trees and another rock, as if the road ahead were to split. To the right, a patch of shorter grass and what seems to be more dirt, possibly another road joining into the first. More trees like the one behind the rock lie further.]

Answer (score 57):

### It's [Far Cry 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Far_Cry_3).

I actually found the exact spot this screenshot was taken:

[image: A screen capture of the same scene as in the question, with the camera turned a bit more to the left. Just to the bottom left corner you can see what seems to be the hand of a dark-skinned person driving the jeep.]

Taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/gvy_o9zDg_Q?t=32). It's easier to see in the (low quality) video, but on the left there are the palm in front of the rock, behind which the overhanging tree stands, mirroring the one on the right. The shadow pattern on the road is the same as well.

Comment: I get that new users like to spam tags when submitting a question, but I find it odd that the answer to the question was one of the tags they spammed. Maybe just a coincidence

Comment: @Wondercricket Well, almost: they tagged it with Far Cry 4, which actually looks quite different, especially flora-wise.